# How do you duplicate consonants in a string in python?

Tags: python

**Define** a function called **double_consonants** that doubles all consonants in a string. The function defines one formal parameter which represents the string to be altered. What the function will do is build a new string where all consonants will be doubled. For example, given the value ***‘Computer Science’***, the outputted value would look like: ***‘CCommpputterr SSccienncce’***. You will need the following two variables to help you accomplish this task:

a. A variable that references all upper and lowercase consonants.

b. A variable that references/assigns an empty string. This variable will hold the new string to be built one character at a time.

```
def double_consonants(string_to_alter):
    '''
    @description double all consonants in a string

    @input string_to_alter the original string

    @return an altered version of the original string
        with doubled constonants.
    '''

    consonants = ["b,c,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,m,n,p,q,r,s,t,v,w,x,y,z,B,C,D,F,G,H,J,K,L,M,N,P,Q,R,S,T,V,W,X,Y,Z"]
    no_consonants = ""

    for letter in string_to_alter:
        if letter in consonants:

doubled = double_consonants('Computer Science')
print(doubled)
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I have already defined the function, and assigned my variables. I know that I need a for-loop and if/else statements for this function to work but I have no idea what to put in the if/else statement

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will exactly answer your question but based on the task this can be done with regex.

```
import re

def doubleConsonants(currStr):
    vowelList = ['a','e','i','o','u'," "]
    newStr = ""
    consList = [subStr+subStr if re.match(r"[^\W\daeiou]",subStr) else subStr for subStr in currStr]
    return newStr.join(consList)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    teststr = "Computer Science"
    dStr = doubleConsonants(teststr)
    print(dStr)
```

Here is a simple case that works for your provided example. You may need to adjust the regex pattern for more complicated examples. [^\W\daeiou] excludes digits, non-word characters and vowels. Here is the documentation.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

This doesn't necessarily follow the requirement of a variable that references all uppercase and lower case consonants but it does have a variable that holds an empty string then concatenates a list of strings.